# How to add Arraylist into another Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have one question about adding one Arraylist of Strings into another Arraylist, the code is the following:

```
public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates,int target){
    List<List<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(candidates);
    List<Integer>tempList=new ArrayList<>();
    backtrack(res,tempList,candidates,target,0);
    return res;

}

public void backtrack(List<List<Integer>>res, List<Integer>tempList,
                      int[]nums, int remain, int start){
    if(remain==0) res.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
    if(remain<0) return;
    for(int i=start;i<nums.length;i++){
        tempList.add(nums[i]);
        backtrack(res,tempList,nums,remain-nums[i],i);
        tempList.remove(tempList.size()-1);
    }
}
```

I am wondering in the function of "backtrack", why we need to use the `new Arraylist(tempList)` when we want to add the tempList into the res `Arraylist`. Why can not we just put the tempList into res, like `if(remain==0) res.add(tempList)`,since I thought tempList was already declared as an `arraylist` before and passed as one argument. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you try to put it in there directly?

Comment: Pretty tough to understand what the heck is going on here...butttt it looks like `new Arraylist(tempList)` is creating a copy of your tempList... that way the tempList added to res keeps all the original references and is not changed by tempList.add() and tempList.remove()

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 1):

What this line `res.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));` does, is create a new ArrayList with the same contents as tempList. This allows you to add/remove elements on tempList without it affecting the **shallow** copy added into `res`

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add( "listA" );
    listA.add( "listAA" );

    List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    listB.add( "listB" );
    listB.add( "listBB" );

    // add both our lists above to a new list of lists
    List<List<String>> manyLists = new ArrayList<>();
    manyLists.add( listA );
    manyLists.add( new ArrayList<>( listB ) );

    // clear the contents of both list A and list B
    listA.clear();
    listB.clear();

    // both of these will be empty because we simply added the reference for listA when we did `manyLists.add( listA );`
    System.out.println( "listA contents -> " + listA );
    System.out.println( "listA contents in many lists -> " + manyLists.get( 0 ) );
    System.out.println();

    // listB will be empty, but manyLists.get( 1 ) will not, because we created a copy of listB (a new Object) before adding it to our manyLists
    // So any changes to listB won't affect our new ArrayList in manyLists.get( 1 )
    // NOTE: This does not make a copy of the contents (Objects) in listB (this is only a shallow copy)
    // those still point to the original references (in this case Strings)
    System.out.println( "listB contents -> " + listB );
    System.out.println( "listB contents in many lists -> " + manyLists.get( 1 ) );

}


// Output:

// listA contents -> []
// listA contents in many lists -> []

// listB contents -> []
// listB contents in many lists -> [listB, listBB]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanaiton is so clear and I understand the difference.

Comment: @Zhe no problem, feel free to accept it so I can get some points 